# Table is jumpy when scrolling to bottom of table

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, networking, uiscrollview

*This question relates to another one of my questions, I'm using a similar explanation here:*

I have a search bar and a table view under it. When I search for something a network call is made and 10 items are added to an array to populate the table. When I scroll to the bottom of the table, another network call is made for another 10 items, so now there is 20 items in the array... this could go on because it's an infinite scroll similar to Facebook's news feed.

The problem is that when I reach the bottom of the table and make a new network call for more data, the table jumps/jerks. It only happens here, not when I'm scrolling up and down.

I am using `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100` and `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` which may be the problem based on numerous answers on Stack Overflow but I'm not sure how else to do this.

Any thoughts?

**Update to question 1**

I am not reloading the entire table. Instead, I used `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` as shown here:

```
    func refreshItems(index: Int) {

    // Make to network call to Google Books
    GoogleBooksClient.getBooksFromGoogleBooks(self.searchBar.text!, startIndex: index) { (books, error) -> Void in

        guard let books = books else {
            return
        }

        self.footerView.hidden = false

        self.booksArrayFromNetworkCall += books

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {


            self.tableView.beginUpdates()


            var indexPathsToInsert = [NSIndexPath]()
            for i in self.currentIndexCount..<self.currentIndexCount + 10 {
                indexPathsToInsert.append(NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0))
            }
            self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPathsToInsert, withRowAnimation: .None)


            self.tableView.endUpdates()

            self.isLoading = false

            self.currentIndexCount = self.booksArrayFromNetworkCall.count
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are reloading the whole table, it might be the cause of the jumpiness. You could try reloading a section of it, in an animated way. I'm not sure, but that might help.

This is the code I use for reloading a section with an animation:

```
self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0), withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am not reloading the entire table. Instead, I use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths`. Please see my updated question above with code. Can I still use what you have or do you have another solution?

Comment: Thanks for the update - you could try using the code I provided instead of inserting rows each time, but that actually would be more inefficient than your solution. Is the height for each cell actually 100 always, or does it change. After some looking around, it seems that can impact the jumpiness. The closer you can get to the actual height the better.

Comment: The height changes based on the content and it could vary a lot. I also seen answers like you did where you need to be very close to your estimated height. The problem is, I don't know how to do this without using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. Not sure how to calculate height manually.

Comment: You're on the right track with `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. Have you tried playing with values other than 100?

Comment: Hmm...Unfortunately I'm not sure if I'm going to be able to help much further, but I would love to know the answer once you figure it out. Sorry I couldn't be that much of a help.